# How to make windows operating system to listen to a user defined event?

Tags: windows-8

I have built a windows metro app in csharp and need to find a way to launch this app when the user for example touches with his finger for 5 seconds anywhere in the start menu. 
I have been googling for 2 days but haven't found sth.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported. Windows Store apps can't listen to UI events anywhere outside of their own UI.

Comment: But is there any way for the system itself to listen this event in the way for example it redirects the user in the start manu when the start button is pressed?

Comment: Live tiles and toast notifications